# Do I need to call delete[] on a member array that is declared with a constant value in class decleration?

Tags: c++

here is an example of a code hopefully will demonstrate my confusion

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 5
class Bar
{
private:
    Foo *_myFooArray[MAX_LENGTH];
public:
    Bar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; ++i)
        {
            _myFooArray[i] = new Foo(i);
        }
    }
};
```

Since I am not creating the array with new I don't think I can use delete[] but what if I want to delete the objects that are allocated dynamicly? do I iterate through the array and delete them one at a time? as such;

```
~Bar()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; ++i)
    {
        delete _myFooArray[i];

    }
}
```

I will probably hear some of you screaming at me Use Vectors!! I appreciate that. I just want to learn. Just for completeness, If for some reason I have to use the array as mentioned above, are there anything that I need to pay extra attention besides deleting the array correctly?

Comment: No, we would scream "Use smart pointers!". As of right now, yes, that's how you would do it.

Comment: You will not delete the array, you will delete the objects that the pointers inside the array are pointing at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the rules in C++ when not using smart pointers is "every `new` needs a `delete`."

You *must* use the destructor from your question to avoid leaking memory. The array itself is not allocated using `new` so you do not need to `delete` it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not `delete []` the array. The array is part of your instance's data. The elements you allocate specifically are not, so you should delete them.